# Поведение страницы сайта при вызове рекурсии

Tags: php, mysql, рекурсия

```
function Recursion($brand, $artid)
{
    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT `ArtCanonical`,`MfcNameCanonical`  FROM `do_search_art_syn` WHERE `Art`='" . mysql_real_escape_string($artid) . "' AND `MfcName`='" . mysql_real_escape_string($brand) . "'
"#@%+=FEFGT6R3987EFDF86347GR=+%@#"and  (Art!=ArtCanonical or MfcNameCanonical!=MfcName)";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while ($Row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        if ((!in_array($Row['ArtCanonical'], $art[0])) && (!in_array($Row['MfcNameCanonical'], $art[1]))) {
            $art[0][] = $Row['ArtCanonical'];
            $art[1][] = $Row['MfcNameCanonical'];
            Recursion($Row['MfcNameCanonical'], $Row['ArtCanonical']); //
        }
    }

    return $art;
}

$mas = Recursion('oc47', 'knecht');
```

в браузере в коде странички.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Почему такое поведение страницы сайта? Если убрать внутри рекурсии вызов самой себя, то нормально отображается. Почему?

**Добавлено:**

объявила `$art global` не помогло,

```
global $art;
$art[0][]='';$art[1][]='';
$mas = Recursion('oc47', 'knecht');
```

Comment: А "нормуль" это что значит? У вас в условии  `if` ошибка, у вас переменная `$art` не существует не говоря уж о том что она не массив

Comment: спасибо, переменную $art лучше объявить локальной внутри рекурсии или глобальной, вне функции?

Comment: объявила $art global не помогло,
    global $art;
    $art[0][]='';$art[1][]='';
    $mas = Recursion('oc47', 'knecht');

Comment: Вы что, вслепую пишете код? Надо видеть сообщения об ошибках, проверять значения в переменных. Отладка вам поможет: http://phpfaq.ru/debug

Comment: Добавление ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL); и $result = mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$query); не спасло ситуацию... отображается по-прежнему пустая страница.

Comment: Вам стоит разобраться с выводом ошибок, посмотреть логи например. У вас функция возвращает  переменную, вы можете ее и передавать - `Recursion($brand, $artid, $art=array())` и `$art = Recursion($Row['MfcNameCanonical'], $Row['ArtCanonical'], $art);`